# SED: Why does the replace do not work with $ to indicate end of the line

Tags: regex, sed

I wanted to remove particular comments '//' from the c header file using sed.
I do not understand why placing $ at the end does not work. Please suggest.
Please see the code below.

```
sed -i -e 's,\\(^//\\)\\(#undef TEST_FIRMWARE$\\),\2,' ./XX_HEADER.h
```

If I remove $ at the end the function works but when I place $ it does not. I want to understand the reason.

Comment: try to check if those lines have characters not visible to eyes like whitespace, dos-style line ending, etc.. you can use `cat -tE` or `cat -A` to check

Comment: When Wiktor Stribiżew added the four leading spaces to re-format your `sed`, the edit should have also changed each of the "\\" to just "\"; I tried editing your post further, but that is too small of an edit for SO to accept; could you please make that edit, in order to fix the `sed` command?  thx

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspicious of the beginning-of and end-of metacharacters being inside the capture groups.  Try:

```
sed -i -e 's,^\(//\)\(#undef TEST_FIRMWARE\)$,\2,' ./XX_HEADER.h
```

My version of `sed` does not seem to care, but I do know that I've run into that sort of behavior before, so it might be what is affecting your version of `sed`.

Comment: sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2 on my machine. Placing beginning-of or end-of outside the capture group did not have any effect.

Comment: @sugun  :  in that case, I'm inclined to agree with Sundeep's comment on your question : the next thing to check for are trailing non-visible (either whitespace or non-printing) characters;  `cat -A` might help, or `od -c`; both of those will make non-visible characters / bytes visible